# Airflow priority_weight across different pools

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm using airflow 2.2.0. I'm trying to prioritize one run to finish over having multiple runs for the same dag.
Ideally I want all task of the dag to fully complete, rather than running same tasks in parallel.

In principle, using `priority_weight` this should work. But once I use different pools for each task this is not working anymore.

```
# import random
from airflow.models.pool import Pool
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

from utils.utils import generate_dag
from time import sleep


LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def sleep_and_print(n):
    for i in range(n):
        LOGGER.info(f"Sleeping for {i} seconds")
        sleep(1)


def task1(*args, **kwargs):
    LOGGER.info("task1 started")
    sleep_and_print(10)
    LOGGER.info("task1 finished")
    # if random.randint(0, 1):
        # raise Exception("task1 failed")


def task2(*args, **kwargs):
    LOGGER.info("task2 started")
    sleep_and_print(2)
    LOGGER.info("task2 finished")


def task3(*args, **kwargs):
    LOGGER.info("task3 started")
    sleep_and_print(10)
    LOGGER.info("task3 finished")


def task4(*args, **kwargs):
    LOGGER.info("task4 started")
    sleep_and_print(15)
    LOGGER.info("task4 finished")


def task5(*args, **kwargs):
    LOGGER.info("task5 started")
    sleep_and_print(10)
    LOGGER.info("task5 finished")


def op_task(dag, task_id, task_func, pool, wait='absolute'):
    return PythonOperator(
        task_id=task_id,
        python_callable=task_func,
        weight_rule=wait,
        pool=Pool.get_pool(pool),
        dag=dag
    )


dag = generate_dag('test_prio')

task_1 = op_task(dag, 'task_1', task1, wait='upstream', pool='test_prio')
# task_1 = op_task(dag, 'task_1', task1)
task_2 = op_task(dag, 'task_2', task2, wait='upstream', pool='test_prio2')
task_3 = op_task(dag, 'task_3', task3, wait='upstream', pool='test_prio3')
task_4 = op_task(dag, 'task_4', task4, wait='upstream', pool='test_prio4') 
task_5 = op_task(dag, 'task_5', task5, wait='upstream', pool='test_prio5')

task_1 >> task_2 >> task_3
task_1 >> task_4
task_1 >> task_5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is still in progress in Airflow, there is already an issue raised in github repo here: [https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13975#issuecomment-806538498[][1]](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13975#issuecomment-806538498%5B%5D%5B1%5D)

Answer (score 1):

I understand that `priority_weight` works at `pool` level, within each pool, but not globally. I couldn't find it as explicit as that in the docs, but there are examples and further explanations in this [guide](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-pools) from Astronomer.

From the mentioned article:

> Pools are meant to control parallelism for Task Instances. If instead you are looking to place limits on the number of concurrent DagRuns for a single DAG or all DAGs, check out the max_active_runs and core.max_active_runs_per_dag parameters respectively

So, here is small example to test how `max_active_runs` works for multiple DagRuns of the same DAG:

Docs:

> :param **max_active_runs**: maximum number of active DAG runs, beyond this
> number of DAG runs in a running state, the scheduler won't create
> new active DAG runs

Example:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator

args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
}

with DAG(
    dag_id="example_max_active_runs",
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval="@once",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 11, 3),
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False,
    tags=["example", ],
) as dag:

    main_task = BashOperator(
        task_id="main_task",
        bash_command='echo "waiting.." && sleep 30',
    )

    end = DummyOperator(
        task_id="end",
    )

    main_task >> end
```

Triggering the DAG 3 times from the UI, shows that since `max_active_runs=1`, there is only one run in execution and the others get queueded:

First DagRun:

[image: example_dag_1st_run]

Second DagRun:

[image: example_dag_2nd_run]

Comment: Yes I'm aware of `max_active_runs=1`, it's also achievable with adding `wait_for_downstream=True` in first task. For this dag it's not a problem to have parallels runs, it's even required to run them if we have empty slots.